# Displace Lat/Long by meters

Tags: leaflet, geojson, coordinate-system

Sorry for the inflammatory title, Yes, I know these cannot be added.

Problem: I have a vehicle that is reporting LL84, coordinates. It has a sensor that reports footprints of obstacles (LineString, Polygons, etc.) and the vertices are expressed as a meter/centimeter displacement from the sensor. I would like to use the GPS as the orgin, add a displacement to the sensor, and then offset the LineStrings and Polygons to result in vertices that are in LL84. Why? I want to plot them with Leaflet as a GeoJSON layer.

My initial thoughts are to convert the GPS LL84 to UTM, and then compute the absolute values for the vertices, then convert all the vertices back to LL84 (EPSG3857), Web Mercator, so that the Leaflet base maps work properly.

Is this the best way to do things?

Here are some of the constraints I am under

- This is an add-on to existing code written in C#, DotNet, So I have
  to use libraries such as DotSpatial
- The displacements to the objects are going to be less than 100-200 meters, so it is unlikely to go into the next zone or band of UTM
- However, if would be nice to deal with those cases, too, and that is looking to be messy
- I would like as much accuracy as possible, so the less translation the better, it would also help to cut down time, (latency could be an issue)
- I know that GeoJSON is supposed to support alternative CRS, but I don't think that Leaflet can handle things other than LL84 coordinates in the GeoJSON

Any better suggestions of approach, libraries, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a (big) problem in your approach. UTM projections are well defined even outside their intended zones, only the projection distortion is a bit higher - but still small enough not to manifest itself in these scales if you only cross the zone boundary by a few meters (unless you need a milimeter resolution in which case UTM is not a good choice anyway).

Answer (score 2):

You are in front of a variant of the [first (or direct) geodesic problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy#First_.28direct.29_geodetic_problem).

I've seen GeographicLib used for this purpose more than a few times. See [here](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/), browse around for examples. Use the C# or JS implementation depending on your constraints (translate once in the server or every time in the client, etc).

If you have a PostGIS database, you might prefer to use [ST_Project](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Project.html) instead.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that pointer to the first geodesic problem, I really appreciate learning the theory, not just the answer.